# Cannot create new integrator key in developer sandbox

Tags: docusignapi

I cannot find the 'Add Integrator Key' button on my admin panel. Other people solved this by switching to Classic view, but apparently you can no longer switch back as of this month. Is there still a workaround available, or is it possible to create new keys?

Answer (score 0):

All Demo accounts should be able to create Integrator Keys by navigating to Go to Admin > API and Keys > Add Integrator Key.

Are you sure you've logged in to the Sandbox? if the url doesn't say 'admindemo.docusign.com' you might have accessed a Production environment account.